# JavaScript - Best Practice __proto__ or this To Hold Type Definition

Tags: javascript, prototype

When defining a type in javascript, I have (basically) one of two options.

- Think of `__proto__`/`constructor.prototype` as an ancestor which shouldn't hold current object's fields. In this case, `__proto__`/`constructor.prototype` will be used to hold ancestor's object, while `this` object will hold its own data/fields.
- Think of `__proto__`/`constructor.prototype` as a "prtotoype" of the current object, in this case all current object's data/fields will be added to the "prototype" and the current/`this` object itself will hold no data/fields on its own.

Which of the two choices should i follow?

Are there any other recommendations regarding this topic?

Comment: I don't really understand option 2 - it means all objects of the same class are the same (more or less)...? That sounds like no use.

Comment: Yea, I forgot what was going on with that question.

Comment: ...oh, I realized it was on the top just because of the edit, the question itself is years old. So never mind